# What is the equivalent of a for loop in sparkR?

Tags: sparkr

I need to perform a mathematical operation on all the combinations of columns of my data frame. In R, I would do this using a simple nested for loop. But in sparkR, I don't think for loop is available. How would you suggest I deal with this?

Comment: Would be helpful to know what you need to iterate through.  Within a conventional R loop you can call SparkR functions.  For example, you can use an R for loop and iterate through a list of R data.frames, and convert them into Spark DataFrames, and call the SparkR glm() function on them.  Is it that you are trying to iterate through a SparkR DataFrame?  If so, what are trying to do with each row, and why do you need distributed processing power of Spark to do something to a single row?  Iterating means doing things one at a time - Spark is about doing things in parallel.

Comment: Also, be aware, if you iterate using an R for() loop on a Spark DataFrame, it will select one column at a time.  `for (item in mySparkDF) {str(item)}` returns one column at a time.

Comment: @SpiritusPrana - i need to iterate through the columns not the rows. And each iteration is independent so distributed environment should be useful. An example of what i am trying to do is, if i have a df with columns -col1,col2,col3 . i need to perform -                                             <itr -1> sum(col1)-sum(col2);                                                                <itr -2> sum(col1) - sum(3); and so on for all the combinations of the columns

Answer (score 2):

You can use **foreach** function.

> **foreach(rdd, func)**
>
> **foreachPartition(rdd, func)**

Example:

```
##To print each element in an RDD
  foreach(rdd, function(x) { print(x) })
```

You can Refer the [Documentation for package ‘SparkR’](https://amplab-extras.github.io/SparkR-pkg/rdocs/1.2/index.html)

Comment: the document you provided is for version-0.1 . What i am using right now is 1.6. The function in no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

@avinash continuing from our conversation in comments.  IMO it's important to bear in mind while learning/researching SparkR, the tasks that Spark is best used for, versus the things that it's best to do outside of SparkR.   Spark's power is in processing large data sets, so in your problem the calculation of the column sums is suited to Spark's distributed processing power.  Spark does not however provide features for handling individual values, just DataFrames and columns.  Consequently, the math on the column totals is best done outside of Spark.  Here's how I would approach your problem:

```
# prep R data.frame
col1 <- c(1,2,3)
col2 <- c(4,5,6)
col3 <- c(7,8,9)
rdf <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3)

# create spark DataFrame
sdf <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, rdf)

# use spark to calc totals
sdfSums <- agg(sdf, col1="sum", col2="sum", col3="sum")
names(sdfSums) <- c("col1Sum", "col2Sum", "col3Sum")

# collect the resulting 1 row DataFrame back into an R data.frame
rdfSums <- collect(sdfSums)

# do the math on the values in R
for (i in 1:ncol(rdfSums)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(rdfSums)){
    if (i != j) {
      print(  paste("column",i,"minus column", j,"equals", rdfSums[,i]-rdfSums[,j]))
    }
  }
}
```

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you use SqlContext for your case, Though you haven't provided any reproducible code.